# Why are my ggplot2 legends overlapping in this R program?

Tags: r, ggplot2

My data is:

```
    x   y  z  a   b   c  d    e
1   1   0  0  7   0   7  0    0
2   2   0  0  7   7  14  7    0
3   3   0  0  7  14  21 14    0
4   4   0  0  7  21  28 21    0
5   5   0  0  7  28  35 28    0
6   6   0  0  7  35  42 35    0
7   7   0  0  7  42  49 42    0
8   8   0  0  7  49  56 49    0
9   9   0  0  7  56  63 56    0
10 10   0  0  7  63  70 63    0
11 11   0  0  7  70  77 70    0
12 12   0  0  7  77  84 77    0
13 13   0  0  7  84  91 84    0
14 14   0  0  7  91  98 91    0
15 15   0  0  7  98 105 98    0
```

My code is:

```
ggplot(data=df, aes(x))+
  geom_step(aes(y=d))+
  geom_point(aes(y=e, color="Blue"),shape=1, size=4)+
  geom_step(aes(y=e))+
  geom_point(aes(y=d,color="Red"),size=2)+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text( vjust = 0.5),
        legend.position = "bottom",
        axis.line = element_line(),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_blank())+
  scale_x_continuous("Patient number", labels = x, breaks = x)+
  ylab("time")+
  scale_color_identity(name="Time", breaks = c("Blue", "Red"),
                       labels = c("Wait time", "Idle time"),
                       guide = "legend")
```

I am using the above code and my legends are overlapping. How can I correct it?

Comment: What do you mean by overlappling?

Comment: try `dput(df)` and paste the output

Comment: Can I delete my question? I want to repost it as my data is not displaying well.

Comment: @Khalar Your data is showed!

Comment: @Khalar You want in your legend only circles without filling, right?

Comment: Here overlapping means I am getting both shapes(in geom_point) for both colours in the legends.

Comment: I want a solid circle for one and a circle without filling for other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this approach, it is better using reshaped data than adding geoms one by one as it can be troublesome to modify elements. Here the code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
#Code
df %>% select(c(x,d,e)) %>% pivot_longer(-x) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=x,y=value, color=name,shape=name,group=name,fill=name))+
  geom_step(color='black',show.legend = F)+
  geom_point()+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text( vjust = 0.5),
        legend.position = "bottom",
        axis.line = element_line(),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_blank())+
  ylab("time")+
  scale_color_manual('Time',values=c('red','blue'),
                     labels = c("Wait time", "Idle time"))+
  scale_shape_manual('Time',values=c(21,21),
                     labels = c("Wait time", "Idle time"))+
  scale_fill_manual('Time',values=c('transparent','blue'),
                     labels = c("Wait time", "Idle time"))
```

Output:

[image]

Some data used:

```
#Data
df <- structure(list(x = 1:15, y = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), z = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), a = c(7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L), b = c(0L, 7L, 14L, 21L, 
28L, 35L, 42L, 49L, 56L, 63L, 70L, 77L, 84L, 91L, 98L), c = c(7L, 
14L, 21L, 28L, 35L, 42L, 49L, 56L, 63L, 70L, 77L, 84L, 91L, 98L, 
105L), d = c(0L, 7L, 14L, 21L, 28L, 35L, 42L, 49L, 56L, 63L, 
70L, 77L, 84L, 91L, 98L), e = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", 
"14", "15"))
```

Also, some elements as `breaks` are not present in the post, so I omitted but you can add then when sketching your original plot.

Comment: Thanks for helping me.

Comment: Hi, @Duck  I tried your code but I saw in the plot that the red and blue circles are interchanged in the plot. Instead of getting red circles for d, I am getting blue solid circles which is then contradicting my legends. Could you please help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Khalar Try playing with the labels in the scale options `labels = c("Wait time", "Idle time")` change the order to `labels = c("Idle time", "Wait time")` maybe your data is different!

Comment: Yes, it works. But labels should be in order that of colours. I tried with the same data. Why it's not working that way?

Comment: @Khalar You should also play around the order of colors in the same way as the labels!

Comment: @Khalar Also, if I understand correctly you want to keep same colors and shapes but change the order of elements in legend?

Comment: As you mention colours in values and the labels in scale_color_manual, the red circles represent the label wait time and the blue solid circles represent the label idle time. That is correct. But the problem is that I am not getting red and blue circles as in your plot. In my plot, I got the red and blue circles are interchanged.  I select the columns from the data frame in the same order as yours.

Comment: @Khalar I am a bit confused, maybe some theme defined in your session. Try re starting the session and replicate the plot using the data shared and the code!